# Remove the query string from url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help with htaccess. Would you be so kind to assist a little bit?
I have a URL like this

```
https://example.com/index.php?p=application-intelligence
```

[or]

```
https://example.com/?p=application-intelligence
```

Basically the index.php is passed some parameter 'home' to know which page to load i.e. home.php
So I've tried to follow your post on your blog but with not much luck.

So I'd like the final code to be

https://example.com/application-intelligence

Here's my code.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

Also for the
https://example.com?p=home

I'd like it to be just

https://example.com

Comment: Which URL is not working with your current rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

# handle /?p=home
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?p=home\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L,NE]

# handle /?p=<something>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much anubhava. We are almost there. Now if you go krugle.webtuits.com then navigate to Solutions > Application Security it works. However, if you try another menu, e.g. Solutions > Code Reuse when you are still on Application Security it becomes http://krugle.webtuits.com/application-security?p=code-reuse or if you click on home it becomes http://krugle.webtuits.com/application-security?p=home

Comment: The code works for the first time you click on the link e.g. 
http://krugle.webtuits.com?p=contact-us
becomes
https://krugle.webtuits.com/contact-us
Then if I click on the logo to go back to home it becomes
https://krugle.webtuits.com/contact-us?p=home
I'd like it to be
https://krugle.webtuits.com/

Also when I'm at https://krugle.webtuits.com/contact-us and I navigate to Resources > Krugle Platform it becomes
https://krugle.webtuits.com/contact-us?p=platform

I'd like it become
https://krugle.webtuits.com/platform

Comment: oh that is because of relative links you've used in your HTML source. To fix add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Perfecto. Now we are almost home and dry. One little thing, for anchor links (links that scroll to a section of the page) they are now redirecting to the home page. E.g. on this page https://krugle.webtuits.com/krugle-basic-guide-v6, the sidebar links need to scroll to the anchor.

Comment: Ok. '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#getting-started">Getting Started</a></li>' Here's my code. Is there anything I can change in the href for anchor links to avoid the page navigating to https://krugle.webtuits.com/#getting-started ? This only started after I changed the htaccess so I'm guessing it has to do with the changes I've applied. By default the browser not redirect on href="#anchor-link" Sorry for the many questions.

Comment: Actually I've noticed that if I removed '<base href="/" />' then the anchor links work normally.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have in my apache virtual host conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```